# Best way to get server-side data to client-side script in usercontrol

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm starting to build a UserControl that will live on some SharePoint 2007 PageLayouts. The UserControl's purpose is to display a map of several locations based on the name of the page. So what it needs to do is take the page name, go query a SharePoint list for the relevant collection of geo coordinates, then load them on the map. I've never really done much client side scripting beyond simple modification of elements and academic jquery AJAX calls. So I'm trying to understand what the common practices are for passing data around.

I've seen a lot of stuff online talking about AJAX calls to page methods, which is out because this is a user control. The alternative looks to be ajax calls to a web service. I've built web services before but for consumption by .NET clients. Is [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services) still the way you set up a .net web service to be called by scripts? What about security? What if I only want my page or my site calling the web service and not the general public?

In this case, I'm not sure a service would even be necessary. Can I just retrieve the data and put it on the page during the initial request? Something like json serializing the coordinate collection in the code behind and writing it to a hidden field for javascript to pick up?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of passing values from an usercontrol to javascript.

**ScriptControl:**

Allows you to include a client behavior for your web control. See some Links below:
[Creating Script Controls](http://byatool.com/ui/creating-script-controls-and-love/)
[ASP.NET: Create AJAX Server Controls using the ScriptControl base class](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/05/ASPNET_Create_AJAX_Server_Controls_using_the_ScriptControl_base_class.aspx)
[Asp.Net Ajax ScriptControl Tutorial](http://vincexu.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/aspnet-ajax-scriptcontrol-tutorial.html)

**RegisterStartupScript and RegisterClientScriptBlock:**

Allows you to include client side script blocks on the page. See some Links below:
[Working with Client-Side Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479302)
[Injecting Client-Side Script from an ASP.NET Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975#aspnet-injectclientsidesc_topic2)

**HtmlGenericControl:**

Nothing stops you from creating a script tag dinamically and inserting all your javascript logic into the `InnerHtml` property. It could be done during the initial request.

Example:

```
HtmlGenericControl script = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
script.ID = "script";
script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
script.InnerHtml = "alert('Hey');";

//Insert the script into some asp:Panel
panel.Controls.Add(script);
```

Comment: I never saw this answer, but thank you for taking the time. These seem to be tools for including javascript, also a powerful tool, but I was interested in making data accessible _to_ my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this 4 years later, I can tell my past self this:

1. Yes, just include the json on the page, hidden for JS to pick up. But be aware that this increases the size of your response that must be downloaded by the client browser. Not only does this take more time, but it uses up more of a mobile user's expensive data. If there is a lot of data and some may not be used, retrieving the data, as needed, from a web service may be a better option.
2. REST services are a common solution for responding to AJAX requests. There's not much you can do to secure your data from anonymous users if you want to allow client side scripts from anonymous users to get at it.